# possible for an unhandled Java Exception within a stack to disturb logging

Tags: java, exception, logging, nullpointerexception

I was trying to consider different scenarios for our bug and wanted to verify whether it was possible for the following scenario to  happen.

```
public class Sample {
    static final logger = Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName());

    public void A() {
        try {
            B()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // no logging here
        }
    }

    public void B() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Method B entered");

        Set<?> set;
        set.add(new Sample()); // null pointer exception
    }
}
```

The `Logger` in use is from `java.util`. `B()` has a code that will throw a `NPE` and this `Exception` gets only caught in `A()`. Given that the class is part of a heavy-load real-time multi-threaded system, I am wondering if it is possible that a thread enters `B()`, throws a `NPE` while it is still attempting to complete writing the message `"Method B entered"` onto the log file and causes the `JVM` to throw off the current stack (a.k.a. `Method B`), leaving no log messages to persist in the log file. Is it always guaranteed that the log message would appear in the log file given `B()` hit the line where the `NPE` is thrown?

Comment: According to [Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)'s documentation, `All methods on Logger are multi-thread safe.`. Therefore, that thread that enters `B()` will finish writing to the file and only then will proceed to the `NPE` section.

Comment: @aribeiro Good point... Answers my question. Thank you.